# How to loop through an array of numbers to see which numbers are relevant to another number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to write a simple program in vanilla JavaScript for weightlifting.  The user inputs a certain amount of weight and it returns the specific weight plates to put on each side of the barbell.

I then take that number into a function which subtracts 45 from it to account for the barbell weight then divides that number by 2 which is the amount of weight to put on each side of the bar.

```
const num = document.getElementById("weightAmount").value;

function getWeightAmount (num) {
const newNum = num - 45;
const halfNum = newNum / 2;
return getWeights(halfNum);
}
```

I have an array with each weight plate:

```
let plates = [44, 33, 22, 11, 5.5, 2.75];
```

I'm having trouble correctly looping through the array to get what I want. If I need, say, 60.5 lbs on each side, it should return 44, 11, 5.5. So I need to figure out which numbers in the `plate` array fit in the number returned from my first function.

I have an empty array called `weights` which I want to push the numbers from the `plates` array into that work with the weight which then is returned.

My question is how do I loop through the `plates` array to figure out which weights are needed?

Comment: Find the weight that only divides once into your target weight, add it to the barbell and subtract it from the target weight.  Repeat until target weight is zero.

Comment: You loop through an array with `plates.forEach(function(plate){}}` for `for (let plate of plates) {}`

Comment: Maybe relevant: [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: Well, as mentioned by @FK82, it is Knapsack, but a slightly modified one. It is actually a modified version of a Change-making problem [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem], which itself is a modified version of Knapsack problem.

Comment: @Taylorg: You can either write your own solution by following the answers given below using Dynamic Programming in pseudo-polynomial time, or you can directly use the solution given below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a simple solution below if value of the target weight will always be the sum of the available plates. Assuming the weights array are sorted in a descending order. I loop thought all available weights and will only proceed to the next weight if the total exceeds the total weight you require.

```
function getWeights(targeWeight) {

    let plates = [44, 33, 22, 11, 5.5, 2.75];

    let totalWeight = 0;

    let neededPlates = [];

    let i = 0;

    while(i < plates.length){

        var pweight = totalWeight + plates[i];

        if (pweight > targeWeight) {
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        totalWeight += plates[i];
        neededPlates.push(plates[i]);
    }

    return neededPlates;
}

console.log(getWeights(60.5)); // [44, 11, 5.5]
console.log(getWeights(104.5)); //[44, 44, 11, 5.5]
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution to this is iterating indefinitely until either

- you have a solution
- the problem becomes unsolvable given the set of weights

Every iteration step, you subtract the highest possible weight times the highest possible factor, store both in a suitable data structure (my implementation simply uses an `Object`) and continue.

```js
const plates = [44, 33, 22, 11, 5.5, 2.75];

// We assume that plates is always sorted
const determineWeights = (totalWeight) => {
  let factor = 0;
  let weights = {};

  while (totalWeight > 0) {
    weight = plates.find(weight => Math.floor(totalWeight / weight) > 0);

    // There is no weight we can subtract from the total weight to solve the problem
    // Hence, the problem is unsolvable and we return null to indicate that no solution exists
    if (!weight) { return null; }

    // Determine the factor with which to multiply the weight before we subtract from the total weight an subtract the product
    factor = Math.floor(totalWeight / weight);
    totalWeight = totalWeight - factor * weight;

    // Store weight and factor
    weights[weight] = factor;
  }
  
  return weights;
}


console.log(determineWeights(104.5)); // { "11": 1, "44": 2, "5.5": 1 }
console.log(determineWeights(60.5)); // { "11": 1, "44": 1, "5.5": 1 }
console.log(determineWeights(5.0)); // null
```

The problem is essentially an instance of the [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Note that we assume that `plates` is sorted. Otherwise, `Array.find` will not necessarily retrieve the maximum weight that can be subtracted from the total weight.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution. In the event that the available plates don't add up to the target weight, it will return the combination of available plates that add up closest to the target. Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23425857/get-the-sum-of-array-items-that-are-equal-to-the-target-subset-sum).

```
function createSubsets(numbers, target) {
    // filter out all items larger than target
    numbers = numbers.filter(function (value) {
        return value <= target;
    });

    // sort from largest to smallest
    numbers.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b - a;
    });

    var i;
    var sum = 0;
    var addedIndices = [];

    // go from the largest to the smallest number and
    // add as many of them as long as the sum isn't above target
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (sum + numbers[i] <= target) {
            sum += numbers[i];
            addedIndices.push(i);
        }
    }

    return addedIndices.map(n => numbers[n]);
}
```