# Converting subset sum algorithm from JavaScript to Python

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, list

I have the following code in JavaScript to compute the minimum elements in array whose sum equals `n`:

```
function findMinSum(arr, n){
    if(!arr) return 
    let min 
    for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {

        /* if a number equals the sum, it's obviously
         * the shortest set, just return it
         */
        if (arr[i] == n) return [arr[i]]     

        /* recursively call on subset with
         * sum adjusted for removed element 
         */
        let next = findMinSum(arr.slice(i+1), n-arr[i])

        /* we only care about next if it's shorter then 
         * the shortest thing we've seen so far
         */
        if (next){
            if(min === undefined || next.length < min.length){
                min = [arr[i], ...next]
            }
        }
    }
    return min && min  /* if we found a match return it, otherwise return undefined */
}
```

I got this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55771349/12500294).

I wanted to convert it to Python, so I did the following:

```
def findMinSum(arr, n):
    if not arr:
        return

    min = []
    min_len = len(min)
    for i in range(0, len(arr)):

        if(arr[i] == n):
            return (arr[i])

        next = []
        next = findMinSum(arr[i+1:], n-arr[i])

        if(next == list):
            next_len = len(next)
        else:
            next_len = next

        if(next):
            print(next) # printing next for debugging purpose 
            if( ( not min ) or (next_len < min_len) ):
                min = [ next, arr[i]]

    return min

arr = [8, 6, 1, 5, 9, 3]
get_min = findMinSum(arr, 14)

print(get_min)
```

But when I run this code, I get the following error:

```
3
[3, 1]
9
[[3, 1], 6]
3
[3, 9]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 34, in <module>
    min2 = findMinSum(arr, 14)
  File "test1.py", line 25, in findMinSum
    if( ( not min ) or (next_len < min_len) ):
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

The expected output should be `[8, 6]` or `[9, 5]`.

I can't think of any other way to write the code as I'm a newbie to Python. Also I don't want to import any other module except numpy.

Where did I go wrong with this translation?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What's `list` in `if(next == list):`? Recommend not using `list` `next` or other builtin variable names. Also, skip `()`s in Python for conditionals and return values. You might accidentally make tuples.

Comment: @ggorlen Thankyou! I'm checking whether next is a list or not. Also, I tried changing the variable names still I'm getting the same output.

Comment: That doesn't work then--you want `isinstance` or `type` here. Yeah, `next` is an iterator function, so I'm just writing a general comment, not a solution. Caching `len` calls is also bad practice, and this might be the cause: `min_len = len(min)`. This never gets updated when `min` changes. `min` also overwrites the builtin function `min`.

Comment: BTW, shouldn't the answer be 6, 9, 3?

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks for the suggestions, I'll try implementing them in my code.

Comment: @ggorlen sorry, the sum should be 14, thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a variety of issues here.

- Never overwrite builtins. Python defines `min`, `next` and `list`. If you overwrite them, you may run into very subtle bugs.
- Python doesn't have arrays, it has lists. Never cache calls to `len`--this code doesn't update `min_len = len(min)`, so the value is stale in future comparisons in this loop if `min` is ever updated.
- Avoid unnecessary parentheses around conditionals and return statements since parenthesis are used for creating tuples. `return (arr[i])` should be `return [arr[i]]` (a single element list).
- `min = [ next, arr[i]]` doesn't match `[arr[i], ...next]` either in ordering or unpacking/spreading. Use `min = [arr[i], *next]` to flatten `next`.
- JS and Python treat `undefined`/`None` and boolean array/list values differently. JS treats an empty array as truthy but Python treats empty lists as falsey. `min = []` doesn't capture the original JS code which sets `min = undefined` implicitly, so `if not min` checks both whether `min` is null *or empty*, which is not comparable to the original JS version.
- No need to check types; checking for `None` or `not None` is sufficient.
- `if (next) { if (more stuff ...` can just be one block using `and`. No reason to nest (this is a problem in the original).
- Use `enumerate` instead of `range` to iterate over a list in most cases (if you do use range, `range(0, len(some_list))` can be `range(len(some_list))`.
- Adhere to [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Use `snake_case` for function and variable names.

Here's my re-write:

```
def find_smallest_sum(lst, n):
    if not lst:
        return None

    smallest = None

    for i, e in enumerate(lst):
        if e == n:
            return [e]

        next_lst = find_smallest_sum(lst[i+1:], n - e)

        if next_lst is not None and (smallest is None or len(next_lst) < len(smallest)):
            smallest = [e, *next_lst]

    return smallest

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(find_smallest_sum([10, 0, -1, 20, 25, 30], 59))  # => [10, -1, 20, 30]
    print(find_smallest_sum([8, 6, 1, 5, 9, 3], 14))       # => [5, 9]
```